# Scheduled Python script arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis line of code resumes only when I log into the machine

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, spatial-join, windows-scheduler

I have a python script (scheduled by windows scheduler) on a desktop I remote into.
all lines of code execute without me being remoted into the machine except when it gets to this line of code below it just hangs.  All I have to do is remote back into the machine and it continues without any prompting from me.  Then  It finishes successfully.
Script has been working for months and then all of a sudden this starts happening.

LINE OF CODE THAT HANGS:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(...)
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify the line of code that hangs when I am remoted out of the machine is the call to the arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis method.